# Get the last value of a record based on a time order in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-stream-analytics

In normal SQL server, If I have 3 columns one for time, one for category and one for integer records, If I want to make a column with the last recorded integer of a specific type, then I should use a query like this:

```
SELECT type, time, record,
LAST_VALUE([record]) OVER ( partition by [type] ORDER BY [time] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as LstValue
FROM testteable
```

In case that I want to do the same in Azure Stream Analytics, the query language says it is not supported this function.

Someone has any idea about how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be achived using  `LAST()` in azure stream analytics. it is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt421186.aspx

Comment: I kept searching for it a lot, Thank you very much.. This is exactly what I was looking for. :)